# Disabling shortened citations in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm trying to disable short citations with the `biblatex` style `verbose-ibid`. It does everything I want, except for subsequent citations of the same work, where it only outputs a shortened citation (as confirmed by the manual).

Is it possible to force `biblatex` to use the full citation each time the work is cited for the first time on a new page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done by modifying the `cite` bibmacro, namely, replacing `cite:short` with `cite:full`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:citepages}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx:loccit}%
  \ifciteseen
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\ifboolexpr{
          test {\ifciteibid}
      and
      not test {\iffirstonpage}
        }
          {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
%          {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}}% DELETED
          {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}% NEW
       {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

Some more text \autocite{A01}.

\clearpage

\null\vfill% just for the example

And some more \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or `\usepackage{xpatch}` and `\xpatchbibmacro{cite}{cite:short}{cite:full}{}{}`

Comment: Thank you! But the above solution does not seem to work for me. Compilation fails with the following message :


`! Package biblatex Error: Bibliography macro 'cite:citepages' undefined.`

Maybe this is caused by varying versions of Biblatex? I will see if I can find the file containing the definition of the original macro.

@egreg I don't have xpatch on this machine, but I will try this on my home machine, which should have it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It was indeed a problem with my biblatex being too old. Thank you for the answer!